# Cancel button for form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, window, cgi

I have a "cancel" button in combination with a form. Onclick of the cancel button should stop the form submission. 
A event with e.g. this:

```
global_.history.back();
```

works well, but not

```
global_.close();
```

(global_ is window).

Unfortunately I didn't found a solution. Why I need a cancel button? This form is used on a offline website where the form will start a cgi which needs a long time. The user should be allowed to cancel this operation.

Comment: If the window was not opened with window.open, you can not close it .

Comment: Sure, if it is mine I can, and it is!

Comment: just type window.close in and see the result. this is the same as global_.close() in my example